# Copy activity taking more times to copy the data from On-prem Oracle database to Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to copy the data from Oracle Database to Azure Synapse and it is taking more time around 3 days to copy 900 GB of data.

My Oracle database is an on-prem database and I have configured self-hosted IR.

I have configured the staging as well while copying the data from Oracle on-prem database to Azure Synapse.

Not sure, Why it is taking this much time, how we can check and fix this data copy issues

[image]

Comment: Is the self hosted IR on-premises (close To Oracle)  or in the cloud? That screenshot makes it look like it's still copying to staging and hasn't started copying from staging to Synapse. Are there any waits on the Oracle side?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, self-hosted IR is installed on VM ( not Azure VM ) and how to check if there are any waits on the oracle side, It is only a Copy activity in ADF which copied the table from Oracle to Azure Synapse

Comment: Your Oracle DBA should be able to tell you if there is a hold up on the Oracle side

Comment: This could be due to various things. Some things to think about are: The hardware the Oracle DB is hosted on (You can only read data as fast as the hardware allows), The Network aspect (Throttling, distance from azure datacenter to your on-prem data center, bandwidth/competing processes), the performance of the VM you have self-hosted IR on (can you run only 5 jobs in parallel or 50?), and then finally the Azure side (in your case you are going to Blob, then Azure Synapse, so probably not an issue here, though if you were writing straight to Azure SQL DB, you would make sure DB is scaled)

Comment: I notice you aren't taking advantage of partitioning for parallel connections/table loads, that could help reduce the time taken to load (if your VM is up to the task)

Answer (score 0):

Here, the issue could be due to various reasons. The alternative is to host a growing number of concurrent workloads. Alternatively, you may wish to improve your performance while maintaining your current workload level.

By increasing the number of concurrent tasks that can execute on a node, you can scale up the self-hosted IR.
Scale up is only possible if the node's CPU and memory are not completely occupied.
By adding extra nodes, you can scale out the self-hosted IR (machines).

You may specify the parallelism you want the copy activity to employ by setting the parallel Copies attribute. Consider this parameter to be the maximum number of threads allowed within the copy operation. The threads work in tandem. The threads either read from or write to the sink data storage.

Here, are the referred Docs: [Self-hosted integration runtime scalability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#self-hosted-integration-runtime-scalability) & [High availability and scalability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory#scale-considerations)